# -bash: aws: command not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, macos-mojave

I'm on macOS Mojave Version 10.14.5.

I was following the instructions here

[Installing the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html)

when I got to the part to type

> aws --version

in terminal, and got the response

> -bash: aws: command not found

Here's a screenshot of terminal

[image: terminal]

I looked at the other posts similar to this on stack**overflow**, but they seem to apply to different contexts. They have not helped.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

you need to install python and pip on your mac in order to install the awscli. 
After the installation of python and pip, please use following command to install aws cli with latest version from AWS.

sudo pip install awscli --force-reinstall --upgrade

Comment: Hey. Thank you very much.

Comment: I had already installed awscli with pip3 and added everything to my PATH as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-macos.html#awscli-install-osx-path -- but it was still saying aws command not found.  When I ran the command above only substituting pip for pip3, it started working.

Comment: Do not use `sudo` with `pip install`!

Comment: only worked when I removed sudo as said by @ruohola

Comment: How to tell if you already have python and pip installed?

Comment: for me it only worked with `sudo`

Answer (score 3):

Install python version 3 or higher And Use this command to download aws cli with python3

```
 curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
unzip awscli-bundle.zip
sudo /usr/local/bin/python3 awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

Answer (score 2):

This command works good for me

```
sudo apt install awscli
```

Comment: When I try that I get: `The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt. Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.`

Answer (score 1):

use AWS official guide [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html%5C) to ensure you are installing the latest version.

I have mac and this fixed the issue

```
$ curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.pkg" -o "AWSCLIV2.pkg"
$ sudo installer -pkg AWSCLIV2.pkg -target /
```